# to_categorical and the error ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network

I am having an issue with these lines of code on jupyter notebook:

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
y_train_one_hot = to_categorical(y_train)
y_test_one_hot = to_categorical(y_test)
```

I get this error:

**ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity**

The code that i am testing is from here:
https://github.com/bnsreenu/python_for_microscopists/blob/master/158b_transfer_learning_using_CNN_weights_VGG16_RF.py
And the dataset that i am using is a dog vs cat dataset from kaggle

Comment: Sharing external link not recommend. Can you share standalone code and data here to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!